# Show zeros of $f(z)-w$ is independent of $w$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Suppose $f:\overline{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous, non-constant, holomorphic in $D$, and $f(\partial D)\subset \partial D$.

(i) Show that for any $z\in D, f(z)\in D$.

(ii) Let $w\in D$ and let $n(w)$ denote the number of zeros of the function $f(z)-w$ in $D$, counted with multiplicities. Show that $n(w)$ is finite and independent of $w$.

(iii) Show that $f: D\to D$ is onto.

**My work:** 
For (i), first use the Maximum Modulus Theorem version 2, since $f$ is analytic and continuous on $\overline{D}$, the maximum is attained on the boundary of $D$, so $|f(z)|\le 1, \forall z\in D$. If $|f(z)|=1$ for some $z\in D$, then by Maximum modulus version 1, it must be constant, which contradicts that it is non-constant. So, $|f(z)|<1,\forall z\in D$, that is $f(z)\in D, \forall z\in D$.

**My question:**
For (ii), I tried to use the Rouche's theorem, however, I tried a long time and still cannot figure out how to do, Could anyone kindly help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Show that

$$n(w)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-w} dz$$

Next show that this is the Winding number of $f(\partial D)$ around $w$, which is independent of $w$ since $f(\partial D) \subset \partial D$. To do this, use the fact that if $\gamma(t)$ is a parametrisation of $\partial D$ then $f \circ \gamma$ is a parametrisation of $ f(\partial D)$.

Comment: I suggest showing that $n(w)$ is continuous on $w$; what can you say about a continuous, integer-valued function on a connected domain?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: This solution is already correct, no need to change it. And moreover, the winding number formulation of the argument principle is an important concept to know.

Comment: @Shalop Absolutely. I simply suggested a more basic (albeit less powerful) approach in case winding numbers are too advanced for the OP.

Comment: Aah okay I see.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Could you help explain why $n(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{1}{f(z)-w}dz$? The argument principle says $n(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-w}$, does that mean I need to show $f'(z)=1$?

Comment: @Sherry You are right, that was a typo. Check it now :)